# Grant all table access for a schema to Redshift user

Tags: amazon-redshift

**Scenario** :-

I have a new Redshift user airflow_test which i am using to connect my database.

I gave the permission like this :-

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA easy_test TO airflow_test;
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA easy_test TO airflow_test;
```

When I am trying to run any query like `select * from easy_test.table1`

It is working as expected but the table "**easy_test.table1**" get dropped and recreate every hour.

**Problem** :-

After its recreation when I am trying to run same query `select * from easy_test.table1`, It is giving me permission error.

I am running GRANT command every-time when table recreate.

**Question** :-

How to give permission of a complete schema to a user even if the table will create in future in that schema?

**Note**:- I don't have any user group.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the default privileges of the user that is recreating the table.  Default privileges are what define the grants on tables when they are created in the future.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_DEFAULT_PRIVILEGES.html